# Прошу восстановить мой вопрос

Tags: discussion

В моём вопросе была использована ненормативная лексика. После его удаления модератором я исправил лексику. Прошу проголосовать за восстановление вопроса.
https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/474356/203782

Comment: Можно задать новый вопрос. Без ненормативной лексики.

Comment: Дело в том, что здесь не корректируют тексты. Предложение могут проверить, но не предложение на страницу.